# Version difference? Regex Escape in Java

Tags: java, regex, escaping, version

It seems that the regex escaping works different in different versions of Java.

1. In Java openjdk 16.0.1 the compilation works fine
2. In Java openjdk 11.0.11 this compilation error is thrown:

```
test.java:15: error: illegal escape character
        if (variable.matches("\s*")){
```

I know, that I'm generally on the safe side with `\\`. My question:

Since which version changed this behavior? And why works this?

Comment: `\s`, with _one_ backslash, has no regex meaning.  It either is a control character, or just the letter `s`.

Comment: Looking at the documentation of `String::translateEscapes` in [version 13](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#translateEscapes()) and [version 14](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#translateEscapes()) shows that `"\s"` was introduced in version 14, and encodes a whitespace character.

Comment: Note that this is NOT regex escaping.  It is String literal escaping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior that caught your attention was introduced with the new feature
of [TextBlocks](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/355)

This new feature was first introduced in Java 13 and the specific change which is the reason for the behavior that you observe, came with the second preview of TextBlocks which was included in Java 14 [Text Blocks Second Preview](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/368) .

According to Text Blocks Second Preview

> the new \s escape sequence simply translates to a single space
> (\u0020).
>
> The \s escape sequence can be used in both text blocks and traditional
> string literals.

Also this new feature about TextBlocks was officially included in LTS version of Java 17.

Answer (score 2):

Java 15 [introduced](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7) `\s` as a valid escape sequence meaning "space" (unicode 0x20) in the language standard.

Non-valid escape sequences generate a compile-time error (that's also in the link above). Since before Java 15 that escape sequence wasn't valid, it threw an error. From Java 15 onward it's a valid escape sequence.

Comment: I have already checked with Java 14.0.2 and the feature is already there if you set `Project Language Level : 14(Preview)`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/preview/specs/text-blocks-jls.html